# Package not found (Multi-module spring project)

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have used [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) to create two modules:

**api** (which is Spring Web)

**db** (which is Spring Data MongoDB)

I have put them in the same project, in a way they are now submodules.

Before creating tests, I can `mvn clean install` with a BUILD SUCCESS message. No problem there.

However, if I try to create a test (or even use it in a controller within **main** structure), where it uses a **db** module repository class, to get data from MongoDB, `mvn clean install` will accuse package does not exist, despite IntelliJ can identify and index it and file exists.

Structure is:

```
api
\- src/main/java
  \- com.example.api.controllers
    \- UserController.java
\- src/test/java
  \- com.example.api.controllers
    \- UserControllerTest.java
db
\- src/main/java
  \- com.example.db.repositories
    \- UserRepository.java
model
\- src/main/java
  \- com.example.model
    \- User.java
```

**ApiApplication.java**

```
package com.example.api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.example.api.controllers;

import com.example.api.Constants;
import com.example.db.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.example.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping(Constants.V1 + "user")
    public User getUser() {
        User user = new User("John");
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

Now, if I run `mvn clean install`, I shall receive maven error saying `package com.example.db.repositories does not exist`.

Module **db** is a dependency in module **api** and **api** module is set to be compiled after **db** in parent's pom.

**parent - pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>model</module>
        <module>db</module>
        <module>api</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

**db - pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>db</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

**api - pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>db</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How to make maven see this package?

*New error after having it find the package*

```
2019-01-14 19:16:55.060  WARN 31104 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.db.repositories.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2019-01-14 19:16:55.066  INFO 31104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-01-14 19:16:55.087  INFO 31104 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-14 19:16:55.224 ERROR 31104 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.example.api.controllers.UserController required a bean of type 'com.example.db.repositories.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.db.repositories.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Springboot autodiscovery will descend only from your configuration class down. your application is at

```
com.example.api
```

but the repo is at

```
com.example.db
```

either add a search path to autodiscover .db as well or move your application class to com.example or the db code to com.example.api

Option 1

```
@ComponentScan(“com.example”)
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication  {
```

Option 2

```
@ComponentScan({"com.example.api","com.example.db"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication {
```

You can also add the scanBasePackages attribute to the SpringbootApplication annotation for the same effect.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.example.api","com.example.db"})
public class ExampleApplication {
```

see the docs here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html#scanBasePackages--

Comment: Having them as two separated modules is my main goal on this. So, how could I "add a search path to autodiscover .db as well" ?

Comment: its not about maven modules. its about packages. The autodiscover will search through the java packages below api. I will lookup the annotationparameter for you.

Comment: So, you mean, even if have them as two separated modules, as they are now, and I move the Main class one package up, it will be able to find .db? The annotation you're looking for would do this, preventing me from moving it, then?

Comment: Yes. Its ComponentScan. This is included in SpringbootApplication, you can set a packages argument with an array of packages to scan for components.Its default is the package of the application class (the Configuration, also included in SpringbootApplication)

Answer (score 7):

You are (re-)packaging `db` as a Spring boot "application" rather than a library by using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The jar is **repackaged**, thus adding the `com.example.db.repositories` package (and its classes) in the BOOT-INF folder. This causes the compilation failure.

[image: Boot-repackage]

Simply remove the `<plugin>..</plugin>` part from the `db/pom.xml`. This will create a regular jar that can be imported in the `api` module.

[image: Jar]

Note: I'm assuming that `api` has the `Main` class and will packaged as a boot application.

Comment: I have done as told and I am now receiving a new error. Would you know why i have this message now? Shouldn't Autowired annotation take care of Bean? I have edited the post to show it.

Comment: What's the package of your Main class (I guess in the api module)?

Comment: com.example.api
Then, it is within ApiApplication.java. I have added this class in the last edit.

Comment: Oh my bad, missed it. So the problem is that your `SpringBootApplication` class cannot find the `repositories` package during the "component scan". By default, component scan finds classes that are in the sub-packages beginning from the package of the main class. So the main class must be in `com.example` so that it can find classes under `com.example` or `com.example.api` or `com.example.db` and so on.

Comment: So, you mean that, even if have them as two separated modules, as they are now, and I move the Main class one package up, it will be able to find db?

Comment: Another alternative is to configure `scanBasePackages` explicitly in the annotation `SpringBootApplication` :  `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= { "com.example.db", "com.example.ab" }). I would prefer the former method.

Comment: Yes if you move the class one package up, it would work. Since the classloader is same, packages with the same qualified name in different modules are basically the same.

Comment: Thx. I had `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in the parent pom.xml, thus this plugin was inherited to the child (`db`). When I removed this plugin (so this plugin is just in the `api` pom.xml), project is now buildable.

Comment: If you remove that, starting jar does not work because main class cannot be found. Repackage is not there for nothing

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, API must see the DB class.

Make sure that:

1. The parent project is of packaging-type `pom` ( `<packaging>pom</packaging>`)
2. The version if the api's **dependency** is the same as the version of the db

Comment: Maybe a different process is locking the .jar in the .m2/repository. Can you try to rename `.m2/repository`-folder to `.m2/repository-old` and try again?

Comment: Tried that also, no success. :(